# Pushforward of a smooth map that is not injective

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, differential, pushforward

Given a smooth map $\psi :M\rightarrow N$, we say the vector field $Y$ on $N$ is $\psi$-related to the vector field $X$ on $M$ if for all $x\in M$:
$$d\psi_x(X_x) = Y_{\psi(x)}
$$

Given a diffeomorphism $\phi :M\rightarrow N$, we can define the pushforward of the vector field $X$ on $M$ as the unique vector field $Y$ on $N$ that is $\phi$-related to $X$:
$$\phi_*X = Y
$$
is such that for all $x \in M$
$$d\phi_x(X) = Y_{\phi(x)}
$$

The pushforward is defined more generally for smooth maps $\psi:M\rightarrow N$ in which case it is possible for more than one vector field to be $\psi$-related to $X$ and $\psi_*X$ is not defined.

This seems obvious to me if $\psi$ is not surjective in which case $Y$ could take on any value outside the image of $\psi$.

According to Wikipedia, "A more general situation arises when $\psi$ is surjective. Then a vector field X on M is said to be projectable if for all $y$ in $N$, $d\psi_x(X_x)$ is independent of the choice of $x$ in $\psi^{−1}({y})$."

It makes sense to me that in the above situation we can define $\psi_*X$.

Where my confusion lies is that it seems to me that the definition of $\psi$-relatedness already requires $d\psi_x(X_x)$ to be independent of the choice of $x$ in $\psi^{−1}({y})$: I would've said that was a condition of $d\phi_x(X_x) = Y_{\phi(x)}
$ for all $x$

How is it then, that when $\psi$ is surjective but not injective, that several vector fields are $\psi$-related to $X$ ? How is the pushforward defined for non-injective maps ?

My best guess would be to say that $Y$ is $\psi$-related to $X$ if for all $y \in $ Im($\psi$) there exists $x\in M$ such that
$$d\phi_x(X_x) = Y_{\phi(x)}
$$

Is this on the right track ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you are given a smooth map $\psi \colon M \rightarrow N$ and a vector field $X$ on $M$. Assume there exists some vector field $Y$ on $N$ that is $\psi$-related to $X$. Then we must have:
$$ d\psi_{m} \left( X|_{m} \right) = Y(\psi(m)) $$
for all $m \in M$. This tells you two things:

1. A neccesary condition for the existence of $Y$ is that for all $n \in N$ and $m,m' \in \psi^{-1}(n)$ we must have $d\psi_{m} \left( X|_{m} \right) = d\psi_{m'} \left( X|_{m'} \right)$. This can indeed be rephrased as $d\psi_{m} \left( X|_{m} \right)$ is independent on $m \in \psi^{-1}(n)$.
2. Any $\psi$-related vector field $Y$ to $X$ (if it exists) is determined uniquely on $\operatorname{im}(\psi)$.

In particular, if $\psi$ is surjective there can be at most one $\psi$-related vector field to $X$ and if condition $(1)$ is satisfied, you can try to define $Y(\psi(m)) = d\psi_m \left( X|_{m} \right)$ for all $m \in M$. This is well-defined and **if it is actually a smooth vector field**, this will be the only $\psi$-related vector field to $X$. However, this doesn't have to be the case!

Consider for example $\psi \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\psi(x) = x^3$ and $X = \partial_{x}$. Then $\psi$ is smooth and bijective (in particular, surjective) and
$$ d\psi|_{x} \left( \partial_x \right) = 3x^2 \partial_x|_{x^3} $$
so if you try and define
$$ Y \left( x^3 \right) = 3x^2 \partial_x |_{x^3} \iff Y(x) = 3x^{\frac{2}{3}} \partial_x $$
you see that $Y$ is not smooth. So there isn't any smooth $\psi$-related vector field to $X$.

This situation does cannot arrise if you add further regularity assumptions on $\psi$. For example, if $\psi$ is a submersion then this cannot happen.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am not sure I completely understand the "if it is actually a smooth vector field" part. Must a vector field $Y$ be smooth to be $\psi$-related to $X$ ? Or was that simply a caveat that the pushforward of a vector field is not necessarily smooth ?

Comment: @MrLolo: Well, usually you work with manifolds of a certain regularity (say, smooth) and then all the objects (manifolds, charts, vector fields, forms, metric, etc) must be smooth and all the operations should respect that. I just wanted to emphasize that, contrary to what Wikipedia says, being "projectable" is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a vector field to have a pushforward (of the same regularity).

Answer (score 2):

The pushforward of non-injective maps is defined precisely by projectability.

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and $M\xrightarrow{\phi}N$ a smooth map. Suppose $\phi$ is surjective and not necessarily injective.

Consider $y\in N$ and the following set,
\begin{equation*}
\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}=\phi^{-1}(y), 
\end{equation*}
where $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$.

If $X$ is a vector field on $M$, then it certainly may be the case that
\begin{equation*}
X_{x_i}\neq X_{x_j},\;i\neq j.
\end{equation*}
It may even be the case that
\begin{equation*}
d\phi_{x_i}(X_{x_i})\neq d\phi_{x_j}(X_{x_j}),\;i\neq j.
\end{equation*}
This would be a case when we can have several vector fields $\phi$-related to $X$. If we cannot pick a unique representative, then different choices woud lead to different pushforwards.

However, if we have the condition that
\begin{equation*}
d\phi_{x_i}(X_{x_i})=d\phi_{x_j}(X_{x_j}),\;i\neq j,
\end{equation*}
then we can simply define the pushforward of $X$ as
\begin{equation*}
Y_y=d\phi_{x_i}(X_{x_i}),\;x_i\in\phi^{-1}(y). 
\end{equation*}
And this is well-defined, since by assuming all the vectors pushforward to the same thing, even though the $X_{x_i}$'s may be unequal, the $d\phi_{x_i}(X_i)$'s are independent of the chosen $x_i$.

Also, I believe the wiki article says "A more general situation arises when $\psi$ is surjective," in reference to the case when $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism. $\psi$-relatedness is a definition.

On the other hand, we want to construct $\psi$-related vector fields. We can have the strong condition that $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism. Or, we can have this more general condition that $\psi$ is surjective, and satisfies this "projectability" condition.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear. What confused me initially was that different choices lead to different pushforwards. I see now this is exactly why the projectability condition is required to construct $\psi$-related vector fields.

Comment: @Mr Lolo That’s great! Also, don’t forget to mark either levap’s or my answer as the answer to the question, so then the question becomes answered on the website (assuming you feel as if your question has been answered, and choose whichever you feel answered your question the best).